# Can I still use native third-party lirbraries when using React Native for iOS and Android?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, facebook, react-native

I'm trying out React Native from Facebook, it looks cool.

One of my concerns is that looks like all the code is in JavaScript, is it possible for me to still use third-party Objective-C libraries for iOS and Java libraries for Android?

As I can't build everything from scratch myself, and the current components available for React Native are still not that rich.

Look forward to advice, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes you can use native libraries.

Checkout documentation:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

Remember that android support is not ready, it's suppose to come in about 6 months.